# Eleventy Configuration for subdirectory - for images and static assets

Tags: eleventy

I'm using Eleventy 0.11.0. During development, in the HTML, I have something like:

```
<img src="/images/footer.png" />
```

and I have a folder called "images" in the root. I also configured eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy('images') - so it copies the entire "images" in the _site directory during build.

It all works fine locally, but when I push to the server, it has to go inside a subdirectory called "ssg-pages" - so the src for the images break. I need it to look like:

```
<img src="/ssg-pages/images/footer.png" />
```

Only on Build, but would still like to keep "/images/footer.png" during dev.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this: Create a `_data` file called settings.js. In it, it returns an object that contains a key called site root.

```
module.exports = function() {
    let siteRoot = process.env.SITE_ROOT;

    return {
       siteRoot
    }
}
```

Locally this will not be defined and simply come out as a blank value. In production, set it to `ssg-pages`. Then in your URLs:

```
<img src="{{ settings.siteRoot}}/images/footer.png">
```

Comment: Thank you Raymond. But what I'm doing is simply adding this to a non Node / server side environment - S3. Where environment variables cannot be set. It's basically just a file server. What I do is just drag the whole _site directory in it and it servers the static html files. So in reality, i need it to transform right before it writes to the _site directory

Comment: What if you set it at the command line? So for example, in Unix/Mac, I think you can do: SITE_ROOT="foo" eleventy

Answer (score 0):

*You asked 18 month ago and got no answer. If you still have that problem ...*

Easiest solution would be to use the directory `ssg-pages/image` for local image storage too. Then you will have no hassle with different image file locations in your development and production environment. Move all your image files in your `src` directory to `./src/ssg-pages/images` and reference them with `<img src="/ssg-pages/images/footer.png" />` even locally.

If this is not an option, you might want to change directories with addPassthroughCopy. Use

```
eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy({ "images": "ssg-pages/images" });
```

and your source directory `image` becomes `ssg-pages/images` in the `_site` output. You still reference your pics by `<img src="/ssg-pages/images/footer.png" />`.

But, if you really need different image source pathes in development and production environment, this could be done by using an environment variable in the build script at `package.json` and a suitable shortcode. I can`t see any reason for this approach, but maybe I'm wrong.